# How to clean or convert these data values to gain word count distribution?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have pandas data frame with object type column that has profiling values per user like this:

```
print(df[profile_values]) 
   
1    [\n "ab",\n "abc",\n "abcd"\n]
1    NaN
3    [\n "ab",\n "abcd"\n]
4    NaN
5    [\n "ab"\n]
...
```

Need to trim values or change datatype so that i can count words to find distribution of said words. Like so:

```
word    count
ab      3
abc     1
abcd    2
...
```

Any advice?

EDIT: Values are string type

Comment: what is the python type of your column values?  Is that a string? -> `[\n "ab",\n "abc",\n "abcd"\n]` or a list?

Comment: Yes. they are string values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your dataframe is something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['[\n "ab",\n "abc",\n "abcd"\n]', np.nan, '[\n "ab",\n"abcd"\n]', np.nan, '[\n "ab"\n]'], columns=["profile_values"])
```

There are a few steps.  Convert the literals to lists of strings, `explode` will convert your series of lists to a single series, and then count the repeated values:

```
from ast import literal_eval
counts = df.dropna()["profile_values"].apply(literal_eval).explode().value_counts()
```

output:

```
ab      3
abcd    2
abc     1
Name: profile_values, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This worked like a charm :) Never heard of this mathod. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do three operations.

1. Create a new column with a transformed values of the "profile_values" column into an actual list with:

   ```
   df['new_column'] = [eval(x) for x in df['profile_values']
   ```
2. Create a list outside the dataframe, containing all the words in a single list:

   ```
   single_list = [x for y in df['new_column'] for x in y]
   ```
3. Use a function to count frequencies of lists, like the following:

   ```
   import collections
   counter = collections.Counter(single_list)
   ```

Then you have the frequencies for every word on the list.